# Problem loading MEDV column in Boston Dataset

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Helloz! I am new to pandas usage... I am using the following code to obtain the Boston dataset, but for some reason the least column (medv) is not loading

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
boston = load_boston()
print(boston.data.shape)
print(boston['data'])
print(boston['feature_names'])
df = pd.DataFrame(data=boston['data'], columns=boston['feature_names'])
print(df.head())
```

Comment: df['medv'] = boston.target

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the Boston dataset, but when I load DESCR into pandas, I get a description of the dataset. If you look at the description, it says "Median Value (attribute 14) is usually the target". So I think the attribute value of target is the value of MEDV. Therefore, you can load and paste as follows.

```
print(boston.DESCR) #boston dataset description
dfx = pd.DataFrame(boston.data, columns=boston.feature_names) #original boston dataset
dfy = pd.DataFrame(boston.target, columns=["MEDV"]) #load target attribute and make MEDV dataset
df = pd.concat([dfx, dfy], axis=1) #combine original boston dataset and MEDV dataset
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```